# Drool Integration with spring-boot not working as expected

Tags: spring-boot, drools, drools-kie-server

Problem: Rule(**InterestRate**.drl) getting fired in standalone java code and giving me accurate result

```
package com.test.drool.config;

import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;

import com.test.drool.facts.InterestRate;

public class RunSampleInterestRate {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    KieContainer container= KieServices.Factory.get().getKieClasspathContainer();
InterestRate interestRate=new InterestRate();
interestRate.setLender("RBL");
System.out.println("printing session object before inserting"+interestRate.toString());

    KieSession kieSession=container.newKieSession("ksession-rules"); 
    kieSession.insert(interestRate);

    kieSession.fireAllRules();


        System.out.println(interestRate.getRate());


  }

}
```

gives me expected 12.5 as interest rate.

Problem:I have to integrate this in rest service and I have been trying to test same logic under rest environment and it is not giving me expected results.After firing rules,service
always returns default value 0.0.My Environment is Spring-boot and drool is 6.5.0 final.

**POJO:**

```
package com.test.drool.facts;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class InterestRate {

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "InterestRate [lender=" + lender + ", principal=" + principal + ", store=" + store
        + ", dealer=" + dealer + ", rate=" + rate + "]";
  }
  private String lender;
  private String principal;
  private String store;
  private String dealer;
  private double rate;
  public double getRate() {
    return rate;
  }
  public void setRate(double rate) {
    this.rate = rate;
  }
  public String getLender() {
    return lender;
  }
  public void setLender(String lender) {
    this.lender = lender;
  }
  public String getPrincipal() {
    return principal;
  }
  public void setPrincipal(String principal) {
    this.principal = principal;
  }
  public String getStore() {
    return store;
  }
  public void setStore(String store) {
    this.store = store;
  }
  public String getDealer() {
    return dealer;
  }
  public void setDealer(String dealer) {
    this.dealer = dealer;
  }
}
```

**Bean Config**

```
package com.test.drool.config;

import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
@Configuration
public class DroolDependencyConfig {
@Bean(name="kieContainer")
  public KieContainer kieContainer() {
   return KieServices.Factory.get().getKieClasspathContainer();
  }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
package com.test.drool.controllers;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.test.drool.facts.InterestRate;
import com.test.drool.service.RuleExecuteService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/rule")
public class RuleExecuteController {
@Autowired
  private RuleExecuteService executeService;
private static Logger logger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(RuleExecuteController.class);


 @PostMapping(value = "/execute", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Double> getInterestRate(@RequestBody InterestRate interestRate){
   logger.info(String.format("logging Request Object %s",interestRate.toString()));
    return new ResponseEntity<Double>(executeService.executeRule(interestRate),HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

**RuleServiceImpl:**

```
package com.test.drool.service.impl;

import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.test.drool.facts.InterestRate;
import com.test.drool.service.RuleExecuteService;
@Service
public class RuleExecutorServiceImpl implements RuleExecuteService {
private KieContainer kieContainer;
private static org.slf4j.Logger logger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(RuleExecutorServiceImpl.class);
@Autowired
public RuleExecutorServiceImpl(KieContainer kieContainer) {
this.kieContainer=kieContainer;   
  }
  @Override
  public double executeRule(InterestRate interestRate) {
      logger.info("firing up session and executing rules");

       KieSession  kieSession= kieContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");
          logger.info("Printing object before inserting in session"+interestRate.toString());
       kieSession.insert(interestRate);
       kieSession.fireAllRules();
       System.out.println("returning values from rule execution"+">>>"+interestRate.getRate());
       return interestRate.getRate();
  }

}
```

**DRL file:**

package com.test.drool.facts

```
rule "Interest Rate"
when
    $interestrate := InterestRate(lender.equals("RBL"))  
then
$interestrate.setRate(12.30);

end
```

Gradle dependency:

```
dependencies {
 compile "org.kie:kie-spring:${droolsVersion}"
 compile "org.kie:kie-api:${droolsVersion}"
 compile "org.drools:drools-core:${droolsVersion}"
 compile "org.drools:drools-compiler:${droolsVersion}"
//compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
       compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
   compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
}
```

Comment: Is the lender you pass in RBL? can you add your logging

Comment: yes I have added logger and confirmed  that RBL as a value is getting passed from my rest controller back to my service,where this gets injected in to rulesession.

Comment: I meant add the output of your logging in your question.  Please change your rule and remove the `lender.equals("RBL")` part and see if your rule fires. I expect the issue will be somewhere around there

Comment: The `:=` in the rule looks funny. A `:` is sufficient. Also, `lender == "RBL"` is the standard way of writing this.

Comment: I did those changes ,but point still remains how come same drl file is getting executed fine from StandAlone piece but not from Spring app.That is the crux of this problem.kissession is all we need to execute the rules.Not sure if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason why it works but we kept minimum spring drool in our gradle file.All me and my colleague did was to have only kie-spring and drool-compiler in gradle and it worked like a charm.We also need to exclude some modules of spring since spring boot 1.5 does not work with spring 3.2 on which kie depends.For future spring boot drool development,here is gradle. Just paste it and build and code as you will code for any other spring-boot project.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name 'jboss'
        url 'http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss'
    }
}
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.SR6'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile ('org.kie:kie-spring:6.5.0.Final'){
        exclude group:'org.springframework', module: 'spring-core'
        exclude group:'org.springframework', module: 'spring-tx'
        exclude group:'org.springframework', module: 'spring-beans'
        exclude group:'org.springframework', module: 'spring-context'
    }
    compile "org.drools:drools-compiler:6.5.0.Final"
    compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'

}
task createFolder{
  def configDir = new File(project.buildDir.path+"/libs", "config")
  def keystoreDir = new File(project.buildDir.path+"/libs", "keystore")
  def logDir = new File(project.buildDir.path+"/libs", "log")
  def libDir = new File(project.buildDir.path+"/libs", "lib")

  if(!logDir.exists()){
    logDir.mkdirs()
  }
  delete configDir
  delete libDir
  delete keystoreDir

  libDir.mkdirs()
  configDir.mkdirs()
  keystoreDir.mkdirs()
}

 //copy config
task copyConfig(type: Copy) {   
    into project.buildDir.path+"/libs/config"
    from "config"

}
 //copy keystore
task copyKeystore(type: Copy) { 
    into project.buildDir.path+"/libs/keystore"
    from "keystore"
}

//copy dependencies
task copyRuntimeLibs(type: Copy) {
    into project.buildDir.path+"/libs/lib"
    from configurations.compile

}

task bundleAll(type: Jar){
    dependsOn 'createFolder', 'copyRuntimeLibs', 'copyConfig', 'copyKeystore' 

    manifest { 
        def manifestClasspath = configurations.compile.collect { "lib/" + it.getName() }.join(' ') 
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'rule-service', 
                   'Implementation-Version': version,
                   'Main-Class': 'com.test.drool.starte.RuleStarter',
                   'Class-Path': manifestClasspath
    }  
    baseName=project.name
  from { (configurations.compile - configurations.compile).collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
  with jar
     exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA' 
} 

task zip(type: Zip){
    dependsOn 'bundleAll'
     from 'build/libs'
}
```